# How do you come out of root user?

Tags: root

I'm very new to using Ubuntu so haven't yet learned any of the commands. I've just opened up my first session and I can see that I am logged in as a root user. From everything I've seen online this should be locked and I shouldn't have access. How do I come out of this (and ideally come into my Documents folder) and continue using Ubuntu? Thank you!

Edit: I'm running version 2004.2021.222.0 on a laptop

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running, and how did you install it? And how did you get into root user?

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question with further detail. What version/flavour of ubuntu would be a good start as well as an indication of whether you are using a desktop or server environment.

Comment: I'm running version 2004.2021.222.0, installed it through the software centre as I'm on a institutional owned laptop where I have admin rights. I have no idea how I got into root user, when I open Ubuntu this is the only thing that pops up (base) root@mycomputerID:~#

Comment: Are you running an Ubuntu [bash] shell under Windows, or a full Ubuntu system? I'm asking because I don't recognize what you describe from a full Ubuntu system.

Comment: Looks like a WSL2 version number, which is a very different beast from stock Ubuntu …

Comment: if in your terminal is "$" sign - then your not root but if your root, then you have "#" sign. to exit from # sign in terminal just type `exit` OR if any other process is running -> end this process via pushing "ctrl" + "c" buttons on keyboard and then change user to normal via `exit`. to exit root mode in linux file-manager -> just close all windows from this app and open new window.

Answer (score 0):

Type nano /etc/gdm/custom.conf, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> type AutomaticLogin=, enter and change the value from "root" to your username (only lower cases). Also are you sure you are on root? To check it open terminal and see if you have # (root) or $ (non root) near username@pcname.